# Unable to run driver based tests from CLI using gradle integrationTest

Tags: corda

I have defined my Driver based tests under src/integrationTest/kotlin/com.example.IntegationTest dir of my CorDapp project:

```
class IntegrationTest {
private val nodeAName = CordaX500Name("NodeA", "", "GB")
private val nodeBName = CordaX500Name("NodeB", "", "US")

@Test
fun `run driver test`() {
    driver(DriverParameters(isDebug = true, startNodesInProcess = true)) {
        // This starts three nodes simultaneously with startNode, which returns a future that completes when the node
        // has completed startup. Then these are all resolved with getOrThrow which returns the NodeHandle list.
        val (nodeAHandle, nodeBHandle) = listOf(
                startNode(providedName = nodeAName),
                startNode(providedName = nodeBName)
        ).map { it.getOrThrow() }

        // This test will call via the RPC proxy to find a party of another node to verify that the nodes have
        // started and can communicate. This is a very basic test, in practice tests would be starting flows,
        // and verifying the states in the vault and other important metrics to ensure that your CorDapp is working
        // as intended.
        Assert.assertEquals(nodeAHandle.rpc.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(nodeBName)!!.name, nodeBName)
        Assert.assertEquals(nodeBHandle.rpc.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(nodeAName)!!.name, nodeAName)
    }
}
}
```

If we try to execute the test using `gradle integrationTest` from command line, how can we ensure that the integrationTest got executed successfully?

If tried with Inteliij IDE, the Junit test works as expected with appropriate test reports/logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the integration tests are actually run, you need to use the `clean` argument:

```
./gradlew clean integrationTest
```

The output of this command doesn't always make it clear which tests have been run. You can make it display more information using the `--info` flag:

```
./gradlew clean integrationTest --info
```